# Change DIV margin on interval

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setattribute

I am trying to change the margin of each element, using setAttribute.

How can I able to use my variable **dist** "distance" to decrease value until 10, every after **delay** "interval"?

```
var dist=200; var speed = 2000;

function slideLeft(x){
    dist--; 
    slideSet[x].setAttribute("style","margin-right:"+dist+"px;");   
    setTimeout(slideLeft(x), delay);    
}
```

Take these style and elements for example...

```
.widiv { margin-right:200px; }
```

---

```
<div>
    <div class="widiv" ></div>
    <div class="widiv" ></div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery and its animate feature?

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to avoid jQuery actually.

Comment: Personally I always find the grief of not using it far out weighs the reasons to not use it. But its you're choice at the end of the day.

Comment: A jQuery example would be as simple as `$(slideSet[x]).animate({ 'marginRight': '0px' }, speed);​`

Comment: thanks again, so using concatenation on setAttribute is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code with some changes: See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/4p3xX/

```
var dist = 200, delay = 500,
    slideSet = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

function slideLeft(x) {
    dist--;
    if (dist < 0) return;
    slideSet[x].setAttribute("style", "margin-right:" + dist + "px;");
    setTimeout(function() {
        slideLeft(x);
    }, delay);
}

slideLeft(1);
```

With a few additions to the styling:

```
.widiv { 
    margin-right:200px; 
    float:left; 
    width: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    height: 100px; }
```

The main differences are that when calling setTimeout I'm using a function delegate (`function() { <your code here> }`) to call the *slideLeft* method so that x variable is used correctly - I don't think you can pass a statement into setTimeout without doing it this way.

Also in styling the divs I made sure to include a float left other wise the change to margin *right* doesn't make sense - should this be margin *left* instead?

Comment: I just haven't posted every detail. I have sufficient styling including float and margin. My problem was the timer. Thank you for the help, its working fine now. +15 rep for you mister :)